# subtracting the current post form then whole loop, which is generating all CPT titles

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, functions, loop

```
<select class="title_select minimal">
                    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'plugin', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
                        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                                <option><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></option>
                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </select>
```

## Question →

In this loop I want that the post title of the current post page should be eliminated. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can try setting the `post__not_in` parameter in WP_Query. You must get the current ID first like `$current_id = get_the_ID();`. Than add this to your query: `'post__not_in' => array( $current_id )`. From the [codex of WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters): _Specify post NOT to retrieve._

Comment: Use `get_queried_object_id()` instead of `get_the_ID()`, unless this `<select>` is inside the loop `get_the_ID()` won't reliably be the current page.